# fadeIn Causes a Wrong Event Fires

Tags: jquery, fadein

I want a text to be fadeIn when a mouse goes over a text and then slide left when the mouse goes out. The slide left part works well but the problem with the fadeIn part is that it continuously causes the text to be faded in, then faded out and then again. It seems it refreshes the pages non-stop and causes the wrong event fires (fadeout).

here is the JS:

```
$('#text1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if($('#container2').children().length<3){
        var newEl=document.createElement("p");
        var position=document.getElementById("container2");
        position.appendChild(newEl);
        $(newEl).html('<br>'+'Test Text');
        $(newEl).hide().fadeIn(500);
    }
});

$('#text1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    if($('#container2').children().length>1) {
    $('#container2').children().last().animate({
        opacity:0.0,
        paddingLeft:'+=80',
    },500,function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
   }
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container2">
        <h3 id="text1">Text 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
    <form id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
        <select name='vType' id='vTypeName'>
    <some form>
        </select>
        <br><br>
    <some Radio boxes>
        <br>
        <input id="vsubmit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <br>

    <div id="XXXX">
    <Some Spans>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML, so we can see the relation between #text1 and #container2?

Comment: Where is the fadeIn code? And why don't you use jQuery to create the new element? `$("#container2").append($("p").html("<br>Test Text"))`

Comment: i added  the HTML.

Comment: reason I used JS and not JQuery to add the child was that when I used JQuery to add a child, the parent was also affected or it does not work at all! It was actually my other question that why this happened? I used your jquery but it did not show anything

Answer (score 0):

Working demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/wXrRar

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','#text1',function(){
    if($('#container2').children().length<3){
        var newEl=document.createElement("p");
        var position=document.getElementById("container2");
        position.appendChild(newEl);
        $(newEl).html('<br>'+'Test Text');
        $(newEl).hide().fadeIn(500);
    }
});

$('#text1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    if($('#container2').children().length>1) {
    $('#container2').children().last().animate({
        opacity:0.0,
        paddingLeft:'+=80',
    },500,function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
   }
});
```

part of CSS that causes the issue:

```
h3 {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 0.90em;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 5px solid #c0bcc0;
    border-right: 5px solid #bcbdc0;
    border-top: 5px solid #bcbdc0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #bcbdc0;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: it works for you very well. but for me the problem still exists. It seems the text box is blinking and two events are fired continuously. is it possible that it is because of the CSS?

Comment: may be!! do one thing, share your css

Comment: i just removed CSS formatting for the text box and it worked! I dont know what is the problem in the CSS. I copy it above

Comment: i found it! I removed 'float' part of the CSS and it was fixed! Now, I have two questions: why this float caused that? and also I still cannot add a new child using append in jQuery and I need to do it using JS.

Comment: newchild is added using append? what is issue in that?

Comment: and do you know why floating can cause that issue?